# Yii2- help translate simple mysql update query to active record code

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How can i write this code

```
UPDATE tbl_user SET status=null WHERE status=12 and id != 1
```

to active record code- smth like this

```
$model = User::find()
            ->where(['status' => 12])
            ->andWhere('id != :id', [':id' => 1])
            ->all();
$model->status = null;
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

The active Record  code you proivede seems right 
If the code don't save try using save(false)

```
 $model = User::find()
        ->where(['status' => 12])
        ->andWhere('id != :id', [':id' => 1])
        ->all();
 $model->status = null;
 $model->save(false);
```

And if the values are saved in this case  the check for your validation rules ..

otherwise you want perform a flat update   you can use  a createCommand

```
 $connection->createCommand()
        ->update('table_name', [SET_Values], 'CONDITION')
        ->execute();
```

in you case

```
     $Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
        ->update('your_tbl_user', ['status'=>NULL], 'status=12 AND id != 1')
        ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
$connection ->createCommand()
->update('tbl_user', ['status' =>null], 'status=12 AND id != 1')
->execute();
```